# NSHostingController/View does not respect hosted content size

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following sample SwiftUI view

```
public struct TestView: View {

    public var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 4) {
            ForEach(1..<5) { index in
                Text("Row: \(index)")
                Divider()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

that is embedded in my AppKit app using `NSHostingController`

```
class TestViewController: NSHostingController<TestView> {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: TestView())
    }
}
```

I was expecting the `NSHostingController` to hug its SwiftUI view, instead what I get is a huge hosting controller view with the SwiftUI view centered like this (actual view is much larger, but cropped to save a bit space here):

[image: Hosted SwiftUI View]

I get the same result with `NSHostingView`. I also tried to make the SwiftUI view `fixedSize` or manually set its frame, to no avail.

Why is it not properly fitting the SwiftUI content and how can I fix it?

Comment: Not reproducible (ie. works as expected) - the hosting view is just a regular NSView (just provides context for SwiftUI rendering) and follows constraints as usual. So just check how do you inject your view and how do you apply constrains.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up having to make sure the controllers `NSHostingView` does not create constraints for autoresizing masks.

```
class TestViewController: NSHostingController<TestView>  {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: TestView())
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}
```

This seems to do the trick.